# Terraform cannot find terraform-provider-avi in docker container

Tags: docker, terraform

I am hitting the following error trying to run terraform in a docker image with the terraform-provider-avi.

```
Error: Error asking for user input: 1 error(s) occurred:

* provider.avi: fork/exec /root/.terraform.d/plugins/terraform-provider-avi: no such file or directory
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Server Fault! This is not how it works here. You should post your question and then post the solution as an _Answer_, not as an edit of your question. Please see [here](https://serverfault.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the standard library packages are built as dynamic libs by default in GO and this is not working in the Terraform docker images (why?). To fix this just pass CGO_ENABLED=0 when you are building the plugin.

```
CGO_ENABLED=0 make
```